# Enabling mod_headers on apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I am trying to enable the module "headers" into my apache2 installation on ubuntu 10.04 system, here's some info:

Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

When I run the command:

```
a2enmod headers
```

I get this output:

```
ERROR: Module headers does not exist!
```

but under `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/` I can see there is `mod_headers.so`.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: There is something wrong with my modules, when I access to the webmin's apache modules list it list me just some modules, not every module I can find on `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/` For example: I can't see `mod_rewrite` from the list but I have it in the `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`

Comment: Does it list headers if you just run "a2enmod"?

Comment: Yes but just few of them, here's the list: alias auth_basic authn_file authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_user autoindex cgid deflate dir env mime negotiation proxy proxy_ftp proxy_html proxy_http reqtimeout setenvif ssl status

Comment: sounds like you've already enabled headers. Does it show if you run "a2dismod"?

Comment: nope, here's the list it gives me: alias auth_basic authn_file authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_user autoindex cgid deflate dir env mime negotiation proxy_html reqtimeout setenvif ssl status. There is something strange with the modules handlers, I can see a lot of modules into the apache library folder but I can't activate lot of them, is there a way to rebuild the index of the apache modules handler?

Comment: I solved this, I copied the file headers.load found in the /etc/apache2/mods-available from another apache server installation that I have on another server and then running a2enmod headers activate the module. Now the question is why am I missing some modules files into the /etc/apache2/mods-available? and how to repair this?

Comment: I just got the same error here, and it seems was just a typo. Be sure you have entered the **plural** form: `sudo a2enmod headers`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like someone has deleted the include files for certain mods, instead of removing symlinks like the a2enmod/a2dismod tools do.

Reinstall the apache common files to get these files back in place:

> aptitude reinstall apache2.2-common

Comment: Thanks dude, but If I run that command I will lose any configuration files or something?

Comment: No, they are common files, so unless you have edited those then you're safe. Install apt-file and run `apt-file list apache2.2-common` if you want to see what kind of files that package installs.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution which worked for me

Add this line to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
```

## a2enmod headers

```
service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                               [Fri Sep 11 17:04:33 2015] [warn] module headers_module is already loaded, skipping
 ... waiting [Fri Sep 11 17:04:35 2015] [warn] module headers_module is already loaded, skipping
                                                                                                                                                   [ OK ]
```

After the restart I could delete the `LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so` from from `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and it's further working!